# Ignore if x < 50, unless x = 100. How would this be done?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it something like:

```
if (x > 50) return unless {
  if (x = 100) {
  console.log("x is equal to 100");
  }
```

I know that is not at all how you are supposed to use unless, but I am trying to make it so that if x is over 50, then it should be ignored unless it is 100, and if it is 100, then it should run a command.

Comment: `if (x == 100) {} else if (x > 50)`

Comment: Why test for anything except for `x==100` then?  If everything else is ignored...

Comment: Does JS have unless keyword? Is it from ES7 or later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't quite describe what you want to do in the various cases, so here's the most generic code:

```
if (x == 100)
{
    // do whatever you want to do when x is 100
}
else if (x > 50)
{
    // do whatever you want to do when x is (strictly) greater than 50, but not 100
}
else
{
    // do whatever you want to do in all other cases, i.e. when x is less than or equal to 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (x > 50 && x == 100){
  console.log("x is equal to 100");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that everything over 50 should be ignored, presumably you care about x < 50. In that case, you can use this logic:

```
if (x < 50) {
    // Not ignored
} else if (x == 100) {
    // Special case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do doesn't make sense.  If all you need to know is if x is 100, then nothing else matters.  Who cares if x is greater than 50 if you're not handling it.

```
if(x == 100){
    console.log("X is 100");
}
```

Comment: Well obviously I need to have x not equal to anything over 50 unless its 100, or else I wouldn't have had the first part in the first place.